# JSF Validation per property

Tags: jsf

When a form is submitted, some properties pass validation and some don't. If any of the properties fail validation, the model is not updated. I was wondering, is it possible to change this default behavior and have the properties that pass validation (and only them) updated with their new values in the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not directly possible without providing your own [`LifeCycle`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html) implementation. This behaviour is namely explicitly definied in the JSF specification. Doing things differently would mean that you void the JSF specification.

What's the rationale behind this question? If you elaborate that, you may get easier workable solutions.

---

**Update**: the requirement is sound. You want to *autosave* forms. You may find this [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-jsf1.html) useful then.

Comment: Just curious I suppose. I wanted the user to be able to enter some data for an entry then to be able to continue writing where he left off. By this I mean if he left and revisited the page in the same session or even in different sessions (with the help of persistence). I would use AJAX to achieve this.

Regards